# how c++ setprecision manipulator work?

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why the output of this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
  double y = 123.456;
  std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left)
            << std::setfill('*')
            << std::setw(8)
            << std::setprecision(3)
            << y;
}
```

is this:

```
123*****
```

Comment: Because that's exactly and specifically what you asked for. Do you want to know _how_ it works (as the title), or _why_ it does that (as in the body)? They're different questions.

Comment: @Useless i mean why it does that, sorry.

Comment: Did you read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision ?

Comment: @UKMonkey my problem is setprecision() why it remove ".456"

Comment: @Miladranjbar because you asked for the precision of 3.  Not 3 decimal places.  The example on the above site gives `default precision (6): 3.14159`  to which you'll note there are only 5 decimal places

Comment: On a side note, you can use the [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) manipulator instead of using `std::setiosflags(std::ios::left)`

Answer (score 1):

On the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice that it is not a minimum and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.

In both the **fixed** and **scientific** notations, the precision field specifies exactly how many digits to display after the decimal point, even if this includes trailing decimal zeros. The number of digits before the decimal point does not matter in this case.

thanks @UKMonkey.

```
cout<<setprecision(5)<<1234.567;
    // output will be : 1234.5
```